# Copilot token request failed - For Github Copilot Chat

Tags: visual-studio, github-copilot

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.7.4
I am able to login and use Github Copilot but not the Copilot Chat
In the VSCode everything works fine.

For Copilot I have the following login message:
Auth Status: OK
Successfully authorized GitHub Copilot.

But for Copilot chat

```
[Conversations Information] [CopilotClient] Need to get an auth token.
[Conversations Error] [CopilotClient] Copilot token request failed:
StreamJsonRpc.RemoteMethodNotFoundException: No method by the name '$/invokeProxy/1/GetEditorVersionAsync' is found.
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.InvokeCoreAsync[TResult](RequestId id, String targetName, IReadOnlyList`1 arguments, IReadOnlyList`1 positionalArgumentDeclaredTypes, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 namedArgumentDeclaredTypes, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isParameterObject)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Conversations.CopilotClient.CopilotAuthTokenManager.GetTokenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, TelemetryScope`1 scope)
   in D:\a\_work\1\s\CopilotClient\CopilotAuthTokenManager.cs:line 241
```

I've tried uninstalling the Copilot extensions and logging in and out of the Github and Microsoft accounts.
But Github Copilot doesn't appear in the VS View menu.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uninstalling all "Copilot" extensions. Including Copilot Services.
Then install just the Copilot Chat extension.
I feel like the "services" extension was the problem in my case.

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks, Aerkain.